# Проблема с socket.io

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, websocket, socket.io

Имеется проект https://github.com/calzoneman/sync, который я хотел запустить на своём сервере. В нём используется nodejs(express), socket.io и mysql. Сделал всё по инструкции(https://github.com/calzoneman/sync/wiki/CyTube-3.0-Installation-Guide). Установил nginx, привязал домен и ssl-сертификат. Но при запуске и подключении через домен выдаёт следующее сообщение об ошибки: "The socket.io library could not be loaded from https://927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru:8443/socket.io/socket.io.js. Ensure that it is not being blocked by a script blocking extension or firewall and try again."

Мой файл /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name 927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru  www.927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru;

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru/privkey.pem;

        location ~ .* {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        }

}
```

Мой файл config.yaml:

```
    listen:
# Default HTTP server - default interface, port 8080
  - ip: ''
    port: 8080
    http: true
# Uncomment below to enable HTTPS/SSL websockets
# Note that you must also set https->enabled = true in the https definition
  - ip: ''
    port: 8443
    https: true
    io: true
# Default Socket.IO server - default interface, port 1337
#  - ip: ''
#    port: 1337
#    https: true
#    io: false
# Example of how to bind an extra port to HTTP and Socket.IO
#  - ip: ''
#    port: 8081
#    http: true
#    io: true
#    url: 'http://my-other-thing.site.com:8081'

# HTTP server details
http:
  # Even though you may specify multiple ports to listen on for HTTP above,
  # one port must be specified as default for the purposes of generating
  # links with the appropriate port

  # Specifies the root domain for cookies.  If you have multiple domains
  # e.g. a.example.com and b.example.com, the root domain is example.com
  root-domain: '927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru'
  # Specify alternate domains/hosts that are allowed to set the login cookie
  # Leave out the http://
  default-port: 8080
  # Use express-minify to minify CSS and Javascript
  minify: false
  # Max-Age for caching.  Value should be an integer in milliseconds or a string accepted by
  # the `ms` module.  Set to 0 to disable caching.
  alt-domains:
    - '127.0.0.1'
  # Set to false to disable gzip compression
  gzip: true
  # Customize the threshold byte size for applying gzip
  gzip-threshold: 1024
  # Secret used for signed cookies.  Can be anything, but make it unique and hard to guess
  cookie-secret: '2cc33d5dbe13993ccc24b4af6a6a0c321cd370d7'
  index:
    # Maximum number of channels to display on the index page public channel list
    max-entries: 50
  # Configure trusted proxy addresses to map X-Forwarded-For to the client IP.
  # See also: https://github.com/jshttp/proxy-addr
  trust-proxies: ['loopback']

# HTTPS server details
https:
  enabled: true
  # Even though you927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru' may specify multiple ports to listen on for HTTPS above,
  # one port must be specified as default for the purposes of generating
  # links with the appropriate port
  default-port: 8443
  domain: 'https://927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru'
  keyfile: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru/privkey.pem'
  passphrase: ''
  certfile: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru/fullchain.pem'
  cafile: ''
  ciphers: 'HIGH:!DSS:!aNULL@STRENGTH'

# Page template values
# title goes in the upper left corner, description goes in a <meta> tag
html-template:
  title: 'Sync'
  description: 'Free, open source synchtube'

# Socket.IO server details
io:
  # In most cases this will be the same as the http.domain.
  # However, if your HTTP traffic is going through a proxy (e.g. cloudflare)
  # you will want to set up a passthrough domain for socket.io.
  # If the root of this domain is not the same as the root of your HTTP domain
  # (or HTTPS if SSL is enabled), logins won't work.
  domain: 'https://927907-ck10299.tmweb.ru'
  # Even though you may specify multiple ports to listen on for HTTP above,
  # one port must be specified as default for the purposes of generating
  # links with the appropriate port
  default-port: 1337
  # limit the number of concurrent socket connections per IP address
  ip-connection-limit: 10
  cors:
    # Additional origins to allow socket connections from (io.domain and
    # https.domain are included implicitly).
    allowed-origins: []

# YouTube v3 API key
# 1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/, create a new "project" (or choose an existing one)
# 2. Make sure the YouTube Data v3 API is "enabled" for your project: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/youtube.googleapis.com
# 3. Go to "Credentials" on the sidebar of https://console.developers.google.com/, click "Create credentials" and choose type "API key"
# 4. Optionally restrict the key for security, or just copy the key.
# 5. Test your key (may take a few minutes to become active):
#
#    $ export YOUTUBE_API_KEY="your key here"
#    $ curl "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=$YOUTUBE_API_KEY&part=id&maxResults=1&q=test+video&type=video"
youtube-v3-key: 'AIzaSyAxu1BQvXEVeHBAU6xXZKdIhhkHo-zshBw'
# Limit for the number of channels a user can register
max-channels-per-user: 5
# Limit for the number of accounts an IP address can register
max-accounts-per-ip: 5
# Minimum number of seconds between guest logins from the same IP
guest-login-delay: 60

# Allows you to customize the path divider. The /r/ in http://localhost/r/yourchannel
# Acceptable characters are a-z A-Z 0-9 _ and -
channel-path: 'r'
# Allows you to blacklist certain channels.  Users will be automatically kicked
# upon trying to join one.
channel-blacklist: []
# Minutes between saving channel state to disk
channel-save-interval: 5

# Configure periodic clearing of old alias data
aliases:
  # Interval (in milliseconds) between subsequent runs of clearing
  purge-interval: 3600000
  # Maximum age of an alias (in milliseconds) - default 1 month
  max-age: 2592000000

# Workaround for Vimeo blocking my domain
vimeo-workaround: false

# Regular expressions for defining reserved user and channel names and page titles
# The list of regular expressions will be joined with an OR, and compared without
# case sensitivity.
#
# Default: reserve any name containing "admin[istrator]" or "owner" as a word
# but only if it is separated by a dash or underscore (e.g. dadmin is not reserved
# but d-admin is)
reserved-names:
  usernames:
    - '^(.*?[-_])?admin(istrator)?([-_].*)?$'
    - '^(.*?[-_])?owner([-_].*)?$'
  channels:
    - '^(.*?[-_])?admin(istrator)?([-_].*)?$'
    - '^(.*?[-_])?owner([-_].*)?$'
  pagetitles: []

# Provide a contact list for the /contact page
# Example:
# contacts:
#   - name: 'my_name'
#     title: 'administrator
#     email: 'me@my.site'
contacts: []

playlist:
  max-items: 4000
  # How often (in seconds), mediaUpdate packets are broadcast to clients
  update-interval: 5

# If set to true, when the ipThrottle and lastguestlogin rate limiters are cleared
# periodically, the garbage collector will be invoked immediately.
# The server must be invoked with node --expose-gc index.js for this to have any effect.
aggressive-gc: false

# If you have ffmpeg installed, you can query metadata from raw files, allowing
# server-synched raw file playback.  This requires the following:
#   * ffmpeg must be installed on the server
ffmpeg:
  enabled: false
# Executable name for ffprobe if it is not "ffprobe".  On Debian and Ubuntu (on which
# libav is used rather than ffmpeg proper), this is "avprobe"
  ffprobe-exec: 'ffprobe'

link-domain-blacklist: []

# Drop root if started as root!!
setuid:
  enabled: false
  group: 'users'
  user: 'user'
# how long to wait in ms before changing uid/gid
  timeout: 15

# Allows for external services to access the system commandline
# Useful for setups where stdin isn't available such as when using PM2
service-socket:
  enabled: true
  socket: 'service.sock'

# Twitch Client ID for the data API (used for VOD lookups)
# https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md#developer-setup
twitch-client-id: null

poll:
  max-options: 50
```

Настройки для nginx взял отсюда: https://github.com/calzoneman/sync/wiki/CyTube-3.0-Installation-Guide#appendix-a-example-config-using-nginx-with-ssl

ОС: Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Просто ufw блокировал порт